# How to divide sentences based on some special contents, Python,

Tags: python, string

The original question is, given the sentence below, There are five people `A1` to `A5`, they separate sentences based on their own knowledge. For example, `A1`,`A2` and `A4` separate the sentence into two, and `A3` an `A5` do not separate the sentence.

`As shown in Fig. 6, 1-h pretreatment of cells with 25 muM PhoCho or DiC8 inhibited by 30% DNA fragmentation |A1:1M| |A2:1S| |A4:1S| induced by 1 muM DNR and MXT. |A1:2S| |A2:2S| |A3:1M| |A4:2S| |A5:1M|`

The objective is to divide the sentence into 2 sub-sentences: `As shown in Fig. 6, 1-h pretreatment of cells with 25 muM PhoCho or DiC8 inhibited by 30% DNA fragmentation` and `induced by 1 muM DNR and MXT.` Also, each sentence have a five labels provided by the five people. For example, the first sentence should have five labels `1M,1S,1M,1S,1M` and the seconde sentence should have five labels `2S,2S,1M,2S,1M`

I use Python to do the job, first I use `rawinput.split('|')`, store the sentences into the array, then delete all the strings such as `A1:1M`, and then read again these labels and attached in array. It is very complex so is there any easy way to do the job? Such as using the `re` package? Thank you very much.

Comment: "`A1` separate[s] the sentence" - Which sentence? How? Can you come up with a general "separation rule"?

Comment: The rule is that, if meets `|***|`, then separates the sentence. In this example, the sentence should be separate into two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this something you are looking for?

```
>>> re.split(r" (?:\|[^\|]+:[^\|]+\| ?)+", "As shown in Fig. 6, 1-h pretreatment of cells with 25 muM PhoCho or DiC8 inhibited by 30% DNA fragmentation |A1:1M| |A2:1S| |A4:1S| induced by 1 muM DNR and MXT. |A1:2S| |A2:2S| |A3:1M| |A4:2S| |A5:1M|")

['As shown in Fig. 6, 1-h pretreatment of cells with 25 muM PhoCho or DiC8 inhibited by 30% DNA fragmentation',
'induced by 1 muM DNR and MXT.', '']
```

This uses the [re.split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) method to split the input at `(?:\|[^\|]+:[^\|]+\| ?)+`:

- Start with a space `" "`
- `(?: ... )+` one or more of, without "capturing" (if you omit `?:`, you will get everyting that is matched by this part in the result)
- `\|` a literal `|`
- `[^:]+` anything but a colon, one or more times
- `:` a literal colon
- `[^\|]+` anything but a `|`, one or more times
- `\|` , a literal `|`
- and an optional space `" ?"`

Because the input string ends with a separator, `split()` returns an empty string as last result in the list. This behavior applies to both `str.split()` and `re.split()`:

```
>>> "a,b,".split(",")
['a', 'b', '']
>>> re.split("[abc]", "1a2b3c")
['1', '2', '3', '']
```

To remove the empty string from the list, you can simply discard the last element with [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/3456281):

```
>>> "a,b,".split(",")[:-1]
['a', 'b']
>>> re.split("[abc]", "1a2b3c")[:-1]
['1', '2', '3']
```

Comment: Actually, my original data are not nicely formatted, so there may exist `|A1:1MG|`. So I changed your rule to `r" (?:\|.*\| ?)+"`, but I can only get one sentence and a space. I don't know why.

Comment: @flyingmouse that is because `.*` is all chars including `|` and that expression is greedy a grab anything until the last `|`, like in my example use `[^\|]` to search any char other that `|` or be more specific and search only number and letter with `r" (?:\|[A-Z0-9]*:[A-Z0-9]*\| ?)+"`

Comment: My updated answer covers the more general cases now as well.

Comment: Thank you @Jasper, but why there is an empty space in the result? Is it possible to delete it by modifying the `split()`? Thanks a lot~

Comment: You can't fix it by modifying `split`, but it's easily done with slicing. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression to separe the string and then filter each sub-string accordingly, in this case look like re.split is the solution

```
>>> import re
>>> test="""As shown in Fig. 6, 1-h pretreatment of cells with 25 muM PhoCho or DiC8 inhibited by 30% DNA fragmentation |A1:1M| |A2:1S| |A4:1S| induced by 1 muM DNR and MXT. |A1:2S| |A2:2S| |A3:1M| |A4:2S| |A5:1M|"""
>>> re.split(r"(\|[^\|]+\|)",test)
['As shown in Fig. 6, 1-h pretreatment of cells with 25 muM PhoCho or DiC8 inhibited by 30% DNA fragmentation ', '|A1:1M|', ' ', '|A2:1S|', ' ', '|A4:1S|', ' induced by 1 muM DNR and MXT. ', '|A1:2S|', ' ', '|A2:2S|', ' ', '|A3:1M|', ' ', '|A4:2S|', ' ', '|A5:1M|', '']
>>> temp=list(filter(lambda x: not x.startswith("|"),re.split(r"(\|[^\|]+\|)",test)))
>>> temp
['As shown in Fig. 6, 1-h pretreatment of cells with 25 muM PhoCho or DiC8 inhibited by 30% DNA fragmentation ', ' ', ' ', ' induced by 1 muM DNR and MXT. ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', '']
>>> resul=list(filter(bool,map(str.strip,temp)))
>>> resul
['As shown in Fig. 6, 1-h pretreatment of cells with 25 muM PhoCho or DiC8 inhibited by 30% DNA fragmentation', 'induced by 1 muM DNR and MXT.']
>>>
```

with this `r"(\|[^\|]+\|)"` search for a literal `|` and anything that is not `|` that is in between and keep each `|**|` if that is of any use, otherwise the solution of Jasper is better